# How do I prevent ImageMagick convert from scaling images *up*?

Tags: image, imagemagick, resize

I'm using ImageMagick's convert tool to generate image thumbnails for a web application. I'm using notation like so: `600x600>`

The images are indeed scaled to 600px wide/tall (depending on the longer side) and proportions are properly maintained, however images *less* than 600px in either direction are scaled *up* — this behavior is not desired. Is there a way to prevent convert from scaling images up if the destination dimensions both exceed the original image size?

Comment: If your images are smaller than your threshold, why do you need to run them through ImageMagick with that parameter? Why not just convert them over, or do you require all images to be that exact size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the  `widthxheight>` [syntax](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/convert.html)

> `widthxheight>`   Change as per
>   widthxheight but only if an image
>   dimension exceeds a specified
>   dimension.

Examples:

```
[/tmp]# identify -format "%wx%h"  test.gif
172x66 
[/tmp]# convert test.gif -resize '1000x1000>' test2.gif && identify -format "%wx%h"  test2.gif
172x66
[/tmp]# convert test.gif -resize '10x10>' test3.gif && identify -format "%wx%h"  test3.gif
10x4 
[/tmp]# convert test.gif -resize '100x100>' test4.gif && identify -format "%wx%h"  test4.gif
100x38
```

Comment: To clarify: what do you want to happen for a 100x200 image and for a 100x700 image ?

Answer (score 2):

`convert input.png -resize 600x600\> output.png` does indeed work on my installation of ImageMagick.  I would double check that the `>` is being escaped properly and that my version of ImageMagick is recent.